# Realloc overwriting contents of array?

Tags: c, io, realloc

I'm trying to read a file into an array of strings using getline() and realloc(). I have used very similar code in the past for tokenizing strings and everything worked correctly. I'll consider the sample input file as

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Here's the code:

```
char** read_input(const char* input_file, char* line){

    FILE *fp;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t nums = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char** res = NULL;

    if ((fp = fopen(input_file, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Incorrect file\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
        if ((res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*) * ++nums)) == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        char to_strip[sizeof(read) * sizeof(char)];
        strcpy(to_strip, line);
        if (line[read - 1] == '\n')
            to_strip[read - 1] = 0;
        else
            line[read] = 0;

        res[nums - 1] = to_strip;
    }
    free(line);

    if ((res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*) * (nums + 1))) == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    res[nums - 1] = 0;

    return res;
}
```

After the loop, if I print the contents of the array, I get:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

despite the fact that if I call print inside the loop, after each assignment to res, I get the right numbers. This is really stumping me, because I can't see what could be wrong except with realloc, but I thought that realloc preserved array contents. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're busy invoking undefined behaviour because you're storing a pointer to `to_strip` in the reallocated array each time, and the pointer goes out of scope each iteration of the loop, and gets overwritten on each iteration which is why you see the same value at the end.  If you printed all the values in the loop rather than just the current value, you'd see first `1`, then `2 2`, then `3 3 3`, then `4 4 4 4` and finally `5 5 5 5 5`.  If you did enough work after returning from this function before printing the results, you'd see garbage as the space would be used for other purposes.

You need to make copies of the lines you store in your reallocated array.  The simplest is to use `strdup()`:

```
res[nums - 1] = strdup(to_strip);
```

Don't forget to release the strings as well as the array of pointers to the strings.

Don't forget to close the file you opened before you return.

It seems odd to pass `line` into the function.  It must either be a null pointer or pointing to space that can be passed to `realloc()`.  Since you then `free()` the space before returning, the calling function needs to know that you've released the space it passed you — and since you didn't know how big it was, you told `getline()` it was of size zero, so it had to be released.  The interface would be cleaner without that parameter; use a local `char *line = 0;` at the start of the function.

Comment: This has solved the problem, thanks. Using strdup() makes sense in this case, I guess I should review pointers, I haven't used them in awhile.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
ssize_t read;

char to_strip[sizeof(read) * sizeof(char)];
strcpy(to_strip, line);
```

`sizeof(read)` - probably 4 or 8 - is a strange amount to allocate for a buffer that you are copying a string into.  I think you meant `char to_strip[ read + 1 ];`. However, later on you have the line:

```
res[nums - 1] = to_strip;
```

which places a pointer to `to_strip` into `res`. However, `to_strip` ceases to exist at the end of the `for` loop, so these will be wild pointers. If your intent is to store all of the text read from the file for later access then you will need to allocate memory for each line.

Jonathan Leffler's suggestion of `strdup` is probably the simplest solution to this; thanks to him for clearing up my erroneous use of `getline`.

You could also do away with `to_strip` entirely, as you could just overwrite the `\n` directly in `line`.

Comment: There's no leaking from calling `getline()` repeatedly; it only allocates extra space if what it's already got is inadequate.  The interface to the function is odd (see notes in my answer), but there isn't a major leak from that.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the behaviour of `getline()`, I thought it `malloc`'d new storage for the line being read. Is this function in any standard?   Actually I have no idea what the `char *line` parameter in OP's code is supposed to be.

Comment: See POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html). It is told how much space it has and where it is.  If that's big enough for the current line, it is used; if not, more space is allocated, and the size and pointer parameters are updated with the new size.  So, it ratchets up the size until it reads the longest line, and doesn't need to reallocate thereafter.

Comment: +1 for the analysis that the size of the `to_strip` array is all wrong. I half noticed it, but didn't mention it in my answer.